# How to have "apt search" give one-line summaries?

Tags: apt, search

`apt-cache` gives one line summaries:

```
$ apt-cache search conway
golly - Game of Life simulator using hashlife algorithm
libclass-delegator-perl - Perl module for a simple and fast object-oriented delegation
...
```

However, `apt search` does not:

```
$ apt search conway
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
golly/impish 3.3-1build1 amd64
  Game of Life simulator using hashlife algorithm
libclass-delegator-perl/impish,impish 0.09-4.1 all
  Perl module for a simple and fast object-oriented delegation
...
```

There is an apt configuration option that makes it return one line summaries, but I cannot figure out what it is. What is this `-o` option, and where is it documented?

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell `apt` to use a custom format, and give it a custom format:

```
$ apt -o apt::cmd::use-format=1 -o apt::cmd::format='${Package} - ${Description}' search conway
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
golly - Game of Life simulator using hashlife algorithm
libclass-delegator-perl - Perl module for a simple and fast object-oriented delegation
libmodule-starter-pbp-perl - Perl module to create new perl modules following best practices
libmoosex-followpbp-perl - Moose extension to name your accessors get_foo() and set_foo()
libperl-critic-perl - Perl module to critique code for best practices
libsub-wrappackages-perl - module to wrap subroutines in packages
libtemplate-plugin-lingua-en-inflect-perl - interface to Lingua::EN::Inflect for the Template Toolkit
sagemath-database-conway-polynomials - Database of Conway polynomials
```

The supported format “variables” aren’t documented (there’s even a comment to that effect in the source code); reading [the `apt` source](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/b89ab5f07e979902da17f23db56cd42ca068ae21/apt-private/private-output.cc#L268) shows they are as follows:

- `${db::Status-Abbrev}`: a summary of the status flags (`B` for broken packages, `g` for upgradable packages, `i` for installed packages, `-` for everything else);
- `${Package}`: the package name;
- `${Architecture}`; the package architecture;
- `${installed:Version}`: the installed version;
- `${candidate:Version}`: the candidate version;
- `${Version}`: the version being listed;
- `${Origin}`: the archive suite;
- `${apt:Status}`: the status string (“installed”, “upgradable”, “automatic” etc.);
- `${color:highlight}`: the escape code for highlights;
- `${color:neutral}`: the escape code to return to the “neutral” colour;
- `${Description}`: the short description;
- `${LongDescription}`: the long description.

The format string matching `apt-cache search`’s output is `${Package} - ${Description}`, whereas [`apt search`’s default short format string](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/b89ab5f07e979902da17f23db56cd42ca068ae21/apt-private/private-search.cc#L97) is `${color:highlight}${Package}${color:neutral}/${Origin} ${Version} ${Architecture}${ }${apt:Status}\n  ${Description}\n`.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can get is the following:

```
$ apt search -o="apt::cmd::use-format=1" conway
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
- golly 3.3-1build1 focal Game of Life simulator using hashlife algorithm
- libclass-delegator-perl 0.09-4 focal,focal Perl module for a simple and fast object-oriented delegation
- libmodule-starter-pbp-perl 0.0.3-2 focal,focal Perl module to create new perl modules following best practices
- libmoosex-followpbp-perl 0.05-2 focal,focal Moose extension to name your accessors get_foo() and set_foo()
- libperl-critic-perl 1.138-1 focal,focal Perl module to critique code for best practices
- libsub-wrappackages-perl 2.01-1 focal,focal module to wrap subroutines in packages
- libtemplate-plugin-lingua-en-inflect-perl 0.04-1 focal,focal interface to Lingua::EN::Inflect for the Template Toolkit
- sagemath-database-conway-polynomials 0.5-7 focal,focal Database of Conway polynomials
```

The file I found with configuration options (Ubuntu 20.04) is:

```
/usr/share/doc/apt/examples/configure-index
```

There's the option

```
apt::cmd::format "<STRING>";
```

But [I can't make it work](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s05s01.en.html#secDisplayFormat) (aptitude) nor find examples on how to use it. Someone can maybe take it from here.